# How to know what exactly who/where process run queries in SQL server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ssms, query-optimization, monitor

I have a product that is already released and recently it has been upgraded.
I cloned some databases test for that and now I have disabled all programs link to that database test and use the real database.

But the problem that recently I have to optimize the program and I found something not normal in "Recent Expensive Queries" in Activity Monitor in SQL Server 2014.

Every few seconds (3,4s) always have some queries that have been executed and have printed in "Recent Expensive Queries" but it is in the database test. (example: Database test 1, database test 2, ...)
I promise I have turned off and delete all programs that link to Database test 1, database test 2, ... but it still happened and take a lot of resources from all the systems.
Can anyone help me find that?

Comment: maybe there are some jobs still running against those databases, have you ever checked that?

Comment: How do I check that bro? Where is it located in SSMS 2014?

Comment: Follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/view-a-job?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 0):

Extended Events can be very helpful in analyzing activity. You should be able to capture enough login and host info to figure out what's running the queries.

Comment: Thanks, bro. I have set the database offline and then finger out what happened in my database. So the real problem is there is some db link to other databases. Many thanks to all of you. But actually, i think i don't understand exactly the information in the activity monitor in SSMS.